# asp.net mvc 3: web.config is not being read?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, configuration-files

I created a link to my web.config which is defnined as a central config file defined at solution level. So the project I am having troubles contains a reference to this config file:

web.config:

```
   <configuration>
      <connectionStrings>

        <add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NWind.csdl|res://*/NWind.ssdl|res://*/NWind.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration

Also I created a .edmx file and the connectionstring is  like:

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/NWind.csdl|res://*/NWind.ssdl|res://*/NWind.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Northwind;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

The issue is that my .edmx file wont read the connectionstring:

I am getting an error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object?

```
 string constrng = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindEntities"].ToString();
```

Comment: create the link by adding an existing item in the explorer

Comment: @Ericj how is that more likely then? because we are having this discussion probably:)